# Running an Access ImportExport from vbs fails if vbs is executed from Excel vba - any idea?

Tags: vba, excel, vbscript, openquery

I have an Excel file (file1) with a macro that has this line:

```
Shell "wscript " & SFilename, vbNormalFocus
```

Where "SFilename" is the name of a vbs file.

In the vbs file I have a line:

```
appAccess.DoCmd.RunSavedImportExport ("ImportMonthlyData")
```

Above this line there are several lines like:

```
appAccess.DoCmd.OpenQuery ("Insert Detail")
```

And there is a lot of Excel work going on in the vbs on Excel file2 (not the same file that contains the wscript macro.

When I run the vbs file by double-clicking the vbs in file explorer, everything works great.

When I run the macro from within the Excel file1 via the macro, the vbs fails on the ImportExport line.  The failure is that it cannot file the sheet in Excel from which to importexport, and the sheet name displayed in the error message has a "$" at the end of it.  I don't know if the "$" is something Access does all the time, because it works when I use file explorer or if the "$" is being added on because of some other reason.  However, my guess is this is not the problem.

I believe the problem arises because the ImportExport is trying to find the sheet in Excel file1 instead of file2.

What do you think?  And if this is the problem, how do I rectify it?

Comment: Does it work if (prior to the `Shell`) you change the current directory to be the directory containing the vbs file?

Comment: Use a full path for `SFilename`, not just the file name. Ditto for anywhere else in your code where you rely on the current directory being something it might not be...

Comment: I know it’s not clear because I didn’t show the definition of SFilename, but it does include the full path.  Inside the .vbs file the full path is also set with a chdir.  I’m working on the theory that it’s looking at file1 instead of file2 (both are in the same folder).  Hopefully, I’ll be able to continue this project tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

So, you are trying to import Excel data to Access?  Why now run the whole thing using VBA, which is a lot less cryptic, and much more intuitive, compared to running batch scripts.

Below is generic code to import the data from specific worksheets in all EXCEL files (worksheet names are the same in all files) that are located within a single folder. All of the EXCEL files' worksheets with the same worksheet names must have the data in the same layout and format.

```
Dim strPathFile As String, strFile As String, strPath As String
Dim blnHasFieldNames As Boolean
Dim intWorksheets As Integer

' Replace 3 with the number of worksheets to be imported
' from each EXCEL file
Dim strWorksheets(1 To 3) As String

' Replace 3 with the number of worksheets to be imported
' from each EXCEL file (this code assumes that each worksheet
' with the same name is being imported into a separate table
' for that specific worksheet name)
Dim strTables(1 To 3) As String

' Replace generic worksheet names with the real worksheet names;
' add / delete code lines so that there is one code line for
' each worksheet that is to be imported from each workbook file
strWorksheets(1) = "GenericWorksheetName1"
strWorksheets(2) = "GenericWorksheetName2"
strWorksheets(3) = "GenericWorksheetName3"

' Replace generic table names with the real table names;
' add / delete code lines so that there is one code line for
' each worksheet that is to be imported from each workbook file
strTables(1) = "GenericTableName1"
strTables(2) = "GenericTableName2"
strTables(3) = "GenericTableName3"

' Change this next line to True if the first row in EXCEL worksheet
' has field names
blnHasFieldNames = False

' Replace C:\Documents\ with the real path to the folder that
' contains the EXCEL files
strPath = "C:\Documents\"

' Replace 3 with the number of worksheets to be imported
' from each EXCEL file
For intWorksheets = 1 To 3

      strFile = Dir(strPath & "*.xls")
      Do While Len(strFile) > 0
            strPathFile = strPath & strFile
            DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, _
                  acSpreadsheetTypeExcel9, strTables(intWorksheets), _
                  strPathFile, blnHasFieldNames, _
                  strWorksheets(intWorksheets) & "$"
            strFile = Dir()
      Loop

Next intWorksheets
```

Comment: The vbs script does *a whole lot more* than loading this data from Excel file2 into Access, so it would be a ton of work to try to convert everything to vba.  But I will keep your suggestion in mind for future projects that can be all vba.  Thx.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, Excel is looking in file2 for the worksheet.  I'm not sure why, but as a work around, I simply copied the needed worksheet from file1 to file2, completed the necessary work and then deleted the worksheet.